# cursor BIG HOT SPOT

Tags: windows, cursor, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to enlarge the cursor hot spot? Standard it's only one pix, how about 4 or 8 pix hot spot? I need it for shooting games. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could always decrease your resolution.  That makes the effective area of one "pixel" much greater ;).

There's really no other alternative though.  Mouse input is processed as points on the screen.  There's no way to tell it that the cursor is over several points at once, and even if there were, the game wouldn't know how to interpret that.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a game configuration issue, not a Windows cursor issue, because the game is processing the input and deciding where on the screen your mouse is, to determine where your clicks are.

And if you want to expand the region the game interprets as a 'hit', well, that's cheating :)